# iOS-Charts - Blank Line appears on bottom of chart

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-charts

I'm using iOS-Charts and after upgrading to Swift3, I'm now noticing there is a strange blank space where the description would go at the bottom of the chart. I tried hiding the description (setting it to "" or enabled = false) but it still shows this gap. I'd prefer to just shift everything down so the 0 is nice and neat on the first line. Any ideas?

Image:

[image]
Any ideas how to remove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever have negative values?

Comment: No, good thinking though! It almost seems like this is the spot where the label would go, though. I assume it might be because it's set to "" or something, but I'm not seeing a way to actually remove it. Do you think this could be the reason? Some null/default initialization causes the space, and I need to somehow set hidden on this setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the minimum axis value so that it hide the above line try this code as

```
barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This was it. So hard to figure that out.

Comment: I'm glad it helped